# How can I transfer a value from input text to a button?

Tags: javascript

I want to transfer the value of `id="insertValue"` to variable `X` in function `insert()` on clicking the button ...

```
<input id="insertValue" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="Insert" onclick="insert('x')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`insert(document.getElementById('insertValue').value)` should do it.

But your question has nothing to do with ajax...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

JS:

```
function insert(e){

myValue = document.getElementById('insertValue').value;

// myValue is now set to the contents of the text field 'insertValue'
// let's check it...

alert(myValue);

}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="insertValue" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="Insert" onclick="insert(this)" />
```

I don't understand if you also want to set the value of the button to the contents of the text field. If you want to (and there's no reason you'd need to), just add this in the JS function.

```
e.value = myValue;
```